# how can we access a variable from one package to another package in C?

Tags: c, process

how can we access a variable from one package to another package in C ?
Actually what i am trying to do "If a error occur in one process of server this should notify another process" ?
so any help on this ? I am new to C

Comment: Whats a "package"?

Comment: C does not have packets. Perhaps you mean processes? Or threads?

Comment: You have a lot of choices.  The two processes can communicate via a socket, or shared memory, or through the filesystem, or with semaphores.  Google "Inter process communication".

Comment: IPC works ,thanks william